# Create a custom function in Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm studing Laravel to create my site, but I need to create a custom function to search into my database, and I would like to know how to do that. I know that in Symfony2 I create a Repository Class and I create inside of it the functions that I want to do.

I tried like this:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Information extends Model
{

    public function scopeGetInformationFromFieldName( $query, $param )
    {
        return $query->where( 'field_name', '=', $param );
    }

}
```

But when I run the code, I receive a error:

```
BadMethodCallException {#151 ▼
  #message: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getInformationsFromFieldName()"
  #code: 0
  #file: "/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php"
  #line: 1999
  -trace: array:52 [▶]
}
```

I need to create a Repository, this kind of code, exists in Laravel?

--
**Update 1**:

This is my Controller code:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $skills = \App\Skill::all();
        $informations = \App\Information::getInformationsFromFieldName( "test" )->get();

        return view( "home.index", compact( 'skills' ) );
    }

}
```

-- **Update 2**:

I found my error, I was calling **getInformationsFromFieldName** but my function is **getInformationFromFieldName** without the **plural** for information.

I'm using Laravel 5 in this project.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you calling `scopeGetInformationFromFieldName`? Can you show a code example?